# Unity ScreenToWorldPoint function always returns the camera position even with a z-axis value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a perspective camera in my scene and I have this line of code to get world point of mouse position but it always returns the camera position despite having the z value.

```
Vector2 screenPosition = Input.touches[0].position;
Vector2 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3
        (screenPosition.x, screenPosition.y, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));
```

I have checked the values of variables like camera, touch and screen position. I have also tried some conversions between Vector3 and Vector2 but got no solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `Vector2 touchPosition = ` => you throw away the `Z` component ... so use a `Vector3 touchPosition =` instead? And if your camera is actually positioned on `z = 0` it makes no difference at all

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the answer. I have tried to use a Vector3 instead but it did not work too. Its z-axis works as I expected but x and y are still the same as camera position's. And as for the reason I am using camera position is that I might need to change camera position in future.

Comment: If you want to get a single finger touch position you can use it like this 'Vector3 worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);'. Mouse Position can be used as a touch input too for mobile games but not for multiple touches.

Comment: @PavlosMavris Thank you for the information. I have used mousePosition but unfortunately x and y axis are still same as camera position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to transform the Input's screen position to world, you can use:

```cs
Vector2 screenPosition = Input.touches[0].position;
Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3
        (screenPosition.x, screenPosition.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
```

*(You will want to change the `touchPosition` to `Vector3` since it's in* worldSpace).

This will place the Input on the Camera's near clip plane.

---

You might be wanting to use the screen position as the source for a RayCast into the world though, which will basically cast a ray from the camera's position into the world. If that's the case, you'll want this snippet:

```cs
Vector2 screenPosition = Input.touches[0].position;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(screenPosition);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo))
{
    worldPosition = hitInfo.point;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that the problem was caused by an FOV setting inside the script. I guess it somehow causes a miscalculation while trying to set the FOV and find the world point of mouse position in the same frame. This code here works well without the FOV part. Thanks for your help.

```
Vector3 screenPoint = Input.mousePosition;
screenPoint.z = -cam.transform.position.z;

worldPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
```